# Exact match in Pandas Series after splitting by character

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following Pandas Series:

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(['red', 'green,blue', 'yellow', 'greenish', 'blueish'])
```

How to find the index (or boolean) where, after splitting each element by the character ',', there is an exact match for any given string?

For example, the strings 'green' and 'blue' should both have a unique match at index 1.

Comment: What do you mean by: *there is an exact match for any given string*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(['red', 'green,blue', 'yellow', 'greenish', 'blueish'])
green = series.str.split(',').apply(lambda x:"green" in x)
print(green)
```

gives output

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Explanation: `str.split` at `,` to get lists then use apply and lambda to check if list contains `"green"`.

Comment: Cheers, I suck at Lambda functions.